# Is there any way to get the repeater that raise its sqldatasource selecting?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, sqldatasource

I have a repeater inside another repeater .. and sub repeater needs the parent repeater item to load .. so, on sub repeater sqldatasource selecting I need the parent repeater item .. Is there any way to get it?

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RpFacility" DataSourceID="DSFacility" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div>                                       
                                              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="RpGIDProp"class="nodisplay"Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"GID`enter code here`)%>' />
                                                                                                                                                          <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RpFacilityValue" DataSourceID="DSFacilityValue">

                                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <label><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PropertyName")%></label>

                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:Repeater>





<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSFacility" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:arrecoconnection %>"
    OnSelecting="DSProdPic_Selecting" SelectCommand="">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PIDREf" QueryStringField="PIDREf" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSFacilityValue" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:arrecoconnection %>"
    OnSelecting="DSFacilityValue_Selecting" SelectCommand="">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PIDREf" QueryStringField="PIDREf" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="GIDRef" QueryStringField="GIDRef" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I need to get GID from parent repeater..

Comment: Could you edit your code to use less indentation and more linebreaks, if possible? It is more readable if horizontal scrolling is not necessary.

Comment: I've deleted the some codes